# Invalid package name "@orgname/@lib/selectors": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, npm, lerna

When I publish (`lerna publish from-package`) library with lerna, I have error:

```
name in package.json "@libName/selectors" does not match publish URL "@OrgName/@libName/selectors"
```

If I fix it, I have other error:

```
lerna Invalid package name "@OrgName/@libName/selectors": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

lerna config:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@OrgName"
    }
  }
}
```

I added `repository` and `publishConfig` in package.json files, but is dont fix it

I publish in private repo